# Are there certain keywords that should not be "#defined" by me?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am developing a platform layer for my application in C/C++.

I would like to

`#define WINDOWS // on Windows machines`

`#define ANDROID // on Android phones`

Is it a bad idea to define very common keywords like "WINDOWS" or "ANDROID" due to conflict with other libraries and would it make sense to prefix these keywords with something:

`#define MYLIB_WINDOWS // Not used by any other 3rdparty libraries`

`#define MYLIB_ANDROID`

Comment: On Windows _WIN32 is already defined, why not just use that.

Comment: Additionally to the answer, the prefix is something I've seen very often and think is valuable. Conflicts with macros are sometimes hard to find if the effect is syntactically correct code (but unintended behavior). IMHO, macros in headers are more critical (than in C++ files) concerning this as their effect is broader and harder to foresee at the time of writing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like to

Beware of exposing macros with 'common' names in your library's header files.

Beware also of commonly named macros in private code - particularly if it `#include`s (either directly or indirectly) other library's headers.

You cannot rely on the hope that all library maintainers are as well-behaved as you.

> and would it make sense to prefix these keywords with something:

In general, yes.

A great example of this is the BOOST suite of libraries. BOOST takes great care to ensure that all macros exported by its header files have the prefix `BOOST_`. It is no coincidence that the prefix matches the library's namespace name of `boost::`.

In summary, if your library is implemented in a namespace (and it should be, otherwise you're guilty of polluting the global namespace), please do use a macro prefix that matches it.

Example:

```
namespace mylib { namespace innerthing { }}

#define MYLIB_ON 1
#define MYLIB_OFF 0
#define MYLIB_SETTING MYLIB_ON
#define MYLIB_INNERTHING_SETTING MYLIB_OFF
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR version**

Macros with common name will cause issues sooner or later, so the short answer is "NEVER use a common name for your macro".

**SUGGESTION**

A very useful approach is to prefix your very simple name with the name of your project, which is pretty common practice in include guards.

**PROPER EXPLAINATION (with example)**

As an example, in the past I was working on program, specifically on header P(roject), and had to include a file that, through a not too deep include chain, was including a header where you could find a member function named "Log" (call this header C for class).

It just so happened that, through a very different chain of includes, I also imported the definition of a macro named in the same way: "Log". Call this header M for macro.

The result was that when I tried to compile, depending on the order of the includes in my project, I would either be fine or end up with a bug.

The first step a compiler performs is to call the preprocessor on the source file currently being compiled. Every time if finds an #include it literally replaces the line with a copy paste of the whole header you are including. At the end of a preprocessing you have a big file with inside all the code from your source and all the recursively included headers.

If the code in this final file is in the following order (top to bottom of the file):

C

M

P

Then everything is fine, as the macro in M only affects the code after it.
If the order is instead:

M

C

P

the preprocessor would sawp the function name with the content of the macro.

Assume the code in M is:

```
#define Log printf("Oops")
```

And that the code in C is:

```
class L {
    void Log(const char* message) { printf("%s\n", message); }
};
```

After the preprocessor stage each Log line (after macro declaration) would have been replaced with the content of the macro. That is, the code from C now looks like this:

```
class L {
    void printf("Oops")(const char* message) { printf("%s\n", message); }
};
```

This code clearly will not compile.

The main issue, though, is that the compiling error will have to do with why that line does not compile, which is not the real problem: macro substitution is.

Note that, depending on the macro and the code being replaced, your code might end up compiling but doing a different thing from the one you coded (e.g. think of a constant value being replaced because your constant is named in the same way as a macro).

**USEFUL NOTE**

When debugging the worst macro issue I had gcc version 6.something was utterly useless, because it was focusing only on the post-preprocessor code. Clang version 3.something was, as usual, a saving grace: it immediately told me that there was an X11 macro (3 library layers deep from where I was coding!) with a relatively sensible name (long-ish 2 word name). Unluckily a sensible name for your library might be sensible for the library user code too, which is why even rare name are not enough.

Every macro really need that _ prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to `#define` anything apart from

1. Anything starting with a leading underscore followed by a capital letter.
2. Anything containing a double underscore.
3. A language keyword.
4. `std`.

It's one of the jobs of a compiler writer to make sure that anything else is free for you to use.

Note that POSIX puts further constrains on this including disallowing anything with a `_t` suffix.

But do take note though that 3rd party libraries should also follow these rules so it's incumbent on you to make sure you don't clash with them. (E.g. stuff defined in `windows.h`.) Avoiding using macros as much as possible and using `namespace`s &c. can do some way to prevent clashes.

Comment: It might be worth affirming that the library-specific prefix is a good idea since macros do not have namespaces.

Comment: It [seems](http://eel.is/c++draft/macro.names) that you're also not allowed to re`#define` attributes and identifiers with special meaning (`override` & `final`).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you may want to consider using some existing macros that are typically predefined on those platforms or a library that already provides a nice set of macros, for example [`BOOST_OS_ANDROID` `BOOST_OS_WINDOWS` from boost.predef](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/predef/reference.html#predef.reference.boost_plat_platform_macros) instead of defining your own.

If you are going to write your own conditional compilation macros then you should definitely make sure than names you select are reasonably unique and aren't already used for unrelated purposes somewhere else because name clashes are not something you want to deal with.